# Need piece of code for validation of existing subscriptions

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

I have been struggling with this for over a week. I am working on subscriptions on the android use their In-App Billing Version 3 I built the code and have it running for purchase but as it was done last year this version  did not support subscriptions and since I put this together from the example I don't have code to build the code to use subscriptions.

Here is the code I have in place for purchases and as I understand it I need to alter these to work with subscriptions instead of purchases plus add the code for determining if a subscription is valid on the google server. I do not see code for that right now.

```
    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MI...QAB";
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set
    // this to false).
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(false);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                // complain("1 "+"Problem setting up in-app billing: " +
                // result);
                return;
            }
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });



// Listener that's called when we finish querying the items we own
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
            Inventory inventory) {
        // ///Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // complain("2 "+"Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }
        // ///Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");
        // place code here to proceess purchase without reaccessing database
        if (inventory.hasPurchase(appSKU)) {
            // ///Log.i("Purchase","purchase consumed here");

        //mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(appSKU),mConsumeFinishedListener);

            return;
        }
    }
};

public void order(String appSKU) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, appSKU, RC_REQUEST,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + ","
    // + data);

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else {
        // ///Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}

// Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        // ///Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " +
        // purchase);


        if(purchase == null) {
            ;
        }else {
        String tester1 = purchase.toString();

        // ///Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");
    //  mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);



           // myCallServer(udid, calltype, data, OrderID, ProductId, PurchaseToken) {


        Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
        myBundle.putString("AppTitle", AppTitle);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                IntroALevActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtras(myBundle);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    }

};

// Called when consumption is complete
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
        // ///Log.d(TAG, "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase +
        // ", result: " + result);

        // We know this is the "gas" sku because it's the only one we
        // consume,
        // so we don't check which sku was consumed. If you have more than
        // one
        // sku, you probably should check...
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // successfully consumed, so we apply the effects of the item in
            // our
            // game world's logic, which in our case means filling the gas
            // tank a bit
            alert("You made a purchase");
        } else {
                    ;
        }
    }
};
```

I have looked online but I have only found broken pieces of code to help me determine what the exact method code would be to check for existing subscriptions. If some one could look at my code and supply the method I am missing it would be great. Google examples have usually been good but since subscriptions have just been added to V3 as of Feb 15th there are not a lot of coding examples to build from.

I am struggling so if you have any questions or need additional information just let me know and I will do the best I can to supply it.

Thanks to the stackoverflow members

Answer (score 1):

Even though I'm not using subscriptions in my implementation you can check that in your IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener function. So instead of this:

```
// ///Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");
    // place code here to proceess purchase without reaccessing database
    if (inventory.hasPurchase(appSKU)) {
        // ///Log.i("Purchase","purchase consumed here");

    //mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(appSKU),mConsumeFinishedListener);

        return;
    }
```

Use this:

```
Purchase haspurchase = inventory.getPurchase(appSKU);
if (haspurchase = null) {
    // do something since there wasn't a purchase
}
else {
   // do something if you have the purchase 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To work with in app subscription i think you will gave to call "launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow()" method on IabHelper instance you create.

```
    mHelper.launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow(Activity act, String sku, int requestCode,
    OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener listener, String extraData);
```

OR

```
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(Activity act, String sku, String itemType, int requestCode,
                    OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener listener, String extraData);
```

Where itemType = IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS